# MySQLError in Bulk Insert Command,

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got an error in below query:

```
      INSERT INTO EDGAR.8k_form_doc_info  (ticker, SECAccessionNo, seq, description, document, docUrl, type, size) VALUES ('ATVI','0000950138-03-000610','1','\ACTIVIS\2003 FILINGS\NOV 8-K\','nov8-k.txt','/Archives/edgar/data/718877/000095013803000610/nov8-k.txt','8-K','3102')
```

Error Log:

```
      INSERT INTO EDGAR.8k_form_doc_info  (ticker, SECAccessionNo, seq, description, document, docUrl, type, size) VALUES ('ATVI','0000950138-03-000610','1','\ACTIVIS\2003 FILINGS\NOV 8-K\','nov8-k.txt','/Archives/edgar/data/718877/000095013803000610/nov8-k.txt','8-K','3102')    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nov8-k.txt','/Archives/edgar/data/718877/000095013803000610/nov8-k.txt','8-K','3' at line 2    0.031 sec
```

What is wrong with the query??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is here `,'\ACTIVIS\2003 FILINGS\NOV 8-K\','nov8-k.txt'`. You are actually escaping `'` by saying `\'`. You need to escape the `\` as well. Otherwise, Db engine thinking that string `nov8-k.txt` is not have the starting single quote.

Change your query like

```
INSERT INTO EDGAR.8k_form_doc_info  (ticker, SECAccessionNo, seq, 
description, document, docUrl, type, size) 
VALUES ('ATVI','0000950138-03-000610','1','\\ACTIVIS\\2003 FILINGS\\NOV 8-K\\',
'nov8-k.txt','/Archives/edgar/data/718877/000095013803000610/nov8-k.txt',
'8-K','3102')
```